# Matplotlib Histogram Grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I am currently working with a large dataset and trying to create a histogram for each of the 13 columns with the probability density function plotted.

Below is the code I have been trying with:

```
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    plt.figure(i)
    plt.hist(df[col], density=True, bins='auto')
    mn, mx = plt.xlim()
    plt.xlim(mn, mx)
    kde_xs = np.linspace(mn, mx, 301)
    kde = st.gaussian_kde(df[col], bw_method=0.06)
    plt.plot(kde_xs, kde.pdf(kde_xs), label="PDF")
    plt.legend(loc="upper left")
    plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.show()
```

The code inside the for loop works when applied to individual columns, but when placed in the loop as above it produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Adam-User/PycharmProjects/FinalYearProject/Final/5.1 Histogram.py", line 47, in <module>
    kde = st.gaussian_kde(df[col], bw_method=0.06)
  File "C:\Users\Adam-User\PycharmProjects\FinalYearProject\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\kde.py", line 209, in __init__
    self.set_bandwidth(bw_method=bw_method)
  File "C:\Users\Adam-User\PycharmProjects\FinalYearProject\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\kde.py", line 565, in set_bandwidth
    self._compute_covariance()
  File "C:\Users\Adam-User\PycharmProjects\FinalYearProject\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\kde.py", line 576, in _compute_covariance
    aweights=self.weights))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in cov
  File "C:\Users\Adam-User\PycharmProjects\FinalYearProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2431, in cov
    avg, w_sum = average(X, axis=1, weights=w, returned=True)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in average
  File "C:\Users\Adam-User\PycharmProjects\FinalYearProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 417, in average
    scl = wgt.sum(axis=axis, dtype=result_dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Adam-User\PycharmProjects\FinalYearProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 38, in _sum
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add
```

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: You call `plt.figure()` inside the loop, but you have `plt.show()` outside the loop. So even if the code worked, you would only see the last plot. Do you want all the histograms as subplots in one figure, or do you want a separate figure for each histogram?

Comment: I would like all the histograms as subplots in one figure

Answer (score 1):

Replace `plt.figure(i)` with this line:

```py
plt.subplot(3, 5, i + 1)
```

This will set up a 3-row, 5-column grid of subplots. You can of course choose different numbers, as long as their product is not smaller than your intended number of subplots. The subplots are counted starting from 1, not 0, hence `i + 1`.

All the subsequent plot commands will be assigned to the `i+1`th axes, i.e. drawn on that subplot, until `plt.subplot()` is called again in the next iteration of the loop. So you don't need to change anything else in your code.

---

**Edit:**

Let's test this with seaborn's iris dataset. This contains four continuous measurement columns and one categorical column.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats as st

df = sns.load_dataset("iris")
df = df.drop('species', axis=1)  # drop the categorical column

# following code is exactly as in the question, 
# except for the one changed line I suggested
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)  # as discussed above
    plt.hist(df[col], density=True, bins='auto')
    mn, mx = plt.xlim()
    plt.xlim(mn, mx)
    kde_xs = np.linspace(mn, mx, 301)
    kde = st.gaussian_kde(df[col], bw_method=0.06)
    plt.plot(kde_xs, kde.pdf(kde_xs), label="PDF")
    plt.legend(loc="upper left")
    plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.show()
```

[image: demo plots]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Arne! Unfortunately, this still produced the same error for me.  I tried replacing  `df[col]` with `df[[col]]` and the program ran for a very long time, but crashed without producing any output.

Comment: @adamk95 Hmm, probably a problem with your data then. The code with the one changed line works fine for me. See my edited answer.